# Initialized 2d array of int prints out zero

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to initialize a 2d array using the braces notation as follows:

```
int[][] matrix = {{0, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 3}, {3, 2, 1}};
int[][] out = rotate(matrix);

for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
        System.out.print(matrix[i][j] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

For the output, I am getting

```
0 0 0  
0 0 0  
0 0 0
```

Can someone tell me the problem?

Comment: The exact same code works correctly for me. Are you sure matrix isn't being modifed somewhere else?

Comment: that is not true with just provided code, http://ideone.com/H9TM9h

Comment: Never mind. I passed the matrix into a function (I edited the code), and it seems to have modified the matrix, even though I thought it arguments were only passed by value. Thanks everyone.

Comment: You might want to take a look to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value?page=1&tab=oldest#tab-top